# Use of Bootstrap-select return "$(...).data(...).on is not a function" Type Error

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libcommon/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../libcommon/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-select.css" type="text/css"/> 


$(document).ready(function() {
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', 'All');
});

echo "<select name=\"years_sel\" id=\"mySelectBox\" class=\"selectpicker show-tick form-control\" multiple=\"multiple\" data-live-search=\"true\">";
```

The code is shown above.And i get following error

1.

> TypeError: $(...).data(...).on is not a function

2.

> TypeError: e.stopPropagation is not a function

i included the css still. but no dropdown arrow.

The Drop down look like bellow image

[image]

Comment: have you included jquery script ..?

Comment: yes. i included both jquery and css correctlly

Answer (score 4):

Be sure the selectpicker is fully initialized before setting the value:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', 'All');
```

You can also set the value with jquery's val and then call render:

```
$('.selectpicker').val('All');
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not included Jquery, check if jQuery library is loaded

```
  if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {

    alert("jQuery library is loaded!");

}else{

    alert("jQuery library is not found!");

}
```

Ref: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-check-if-jquery-library-is-loaded/

Comment: jquery library is loaded. am getting the alert "jQuery library is loaded!"

Comment: TypeError: $(...).data(...).on is not a function
http://localhost/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-select.js
Line 732

Comment: $(document)
        .data('keycount', 0)
        .on('keydown', '.selectpicker[data-toggle=dropdown], .selectpicker[role=menu]' , Selectpicker.prototype.keydown) this is the line 732 reffering
        .on('keyup', '.selectpicker[data-toggle=dropdown], .selectpicker[role=menu]' , Selectpicker.prototype.keyup);

Answer (score -2):

Remove this code from your page:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

Use only the `.selectpicker` class to create select boxes.